# Repeat component slot

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I’ve made a component in which I want to repeat the content that is being passed to it to be repeated “n” times. I’ve tried to do this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot v-for="n in amount"></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

But I get the error “Duplicate presence of slot “default” found in the same render tree - this will likely cause render errors.”

Is it possible to repeat the slot content in some other way?

Edit: For a bit more clarification, this is what I'm trying to achieve:

Let's say I have 2 components with these templates:

component1:

```
<div>
    <h1>Hi</h1>
    <img src="hello.jpg">
</div>
```

component 2:

```
<div>
    <h2>Hello</h2>
</div>
```

What I want to templates to turn in to is:

component1:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <h1>Hi</h1>
        <img src="hello.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Hi</h1>
        <img src="hello.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Hi</h1>
        <img src="hello.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

component 2:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <h2>Hello</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Hello</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Hello</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the content that you will pass to that slot? The content should have the `v-for` not the slot.

Comment: I want to use this in component in multiple other components, so the content will be different each time. Basically I want to but the content in a column that has to be repeated, and I want to put that logic in this component.

Comment: But since this component doesn't know what it will receive you have to have the `v-for` in the other components. Does that make sense?

Comment: Well, not really to be honest.. I just want to repeat the content, no matter what the content is. Since I need to wrap each piece of content in another element, and add some logic to it, I want to do it in this component, so I don't have to repeat it for every other component that uses it.

Comment: I'm still not sure of what you look for, but you could use a `template v-for` and iterate over `$children` instead of using `slot`.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify better what the result would be. What I want to do is this:

Let's say I have 2 components, with these templates:

component1:
<div>
<h1>Hi</h1>
<img src="hello.jpg">
</div>

component 2:
<div>
<h2>Hello</h2>
</div>

Comment: And for both of the templates, I want the content to be repeated like so:

component1:

<div>
    <div>
        <h1>Hi</h1>
        <img src="hello.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Hi</h1>
        <img src="hello.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

component 2:

<div>
    <div>
        <h2>Hello</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Hello</h2>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: Well that doesn't work, I'll update my post.

Comment: Ok. Depending on how dynamic the content of those children is you could do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/6oerrfus/

Comment: Sweet! I'll give that a try! Thank you very much!

Comment: If it works as you need I can post a answer on that.